# How to step through semicolons separated tactics sequence in coqide?

Tags: coq, coqide

when constructing proof in coqide, I didn't find a way to step though

```
T1; T2; T3; ...; Tn.
```

one tactic by one tactic. So it became very difficult to **construct** correct proof like the code above. So my question is

- Is there a way to step through the code above or
- How do you construct proof like the code above?

Forward one Command or go to cursor aren't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`t1 ; t2` is not the same as doing first `t1` then `t2`.
If you want to do this you can do `t1. t2.` and this is the way to step through them.

The semicolon serves three purposes, stated for `t1 ; t2`:

- It applies `t2` in all of the subgoals generated by `t1`;
- and it allows backtracking, if `t2` were to fail, it would try a different *success* for `t1` and apply `t2` again on the generated subgoals;
- third, it's the simplest way to write down a tactic that represents a succession of tactics.

If you're lucky and this is the first or third case, then you can modify the script by replacing

```
t1 ; t2
```

by

```
t1. all: t2.
```

using goal selectors.
This way the first step will allow you to see the goals generated by `t1` and the second will show you how `t2` affects them. If you need more precision you can also focus one of the subgoals to see `t2` in action.

When backtracking is involved it becomes much harder to understand what is going on, but I believe it can be avoided at first, or limited to simple cases.
You could for instance say that the goal can be closed by applying an introduction rule (`constructor`) and that then it should be easy.
If multiple intro-rules/constructors apply doing

```
constructor. easy.
```

might result in failure, while

```
constructor ; easy.
```

might succeed. Indeed, if `easy` fails on the first constructor, coq will try the second and so on.

To answer your question about how one would write them, I suppose it can be the result of trial and error, and can mostly stem from factorisation or automation of proof scripts.
Say you have the following proof script:

```
split.
- constructor.
  + assumption.
  + eassumption.
- constructor. eassumption.
```

You might want to summarise it as follows:

```
split ; constructor ; eassumption.
```

I personally don't necessarily recommend it because it becomes harder to maintain and harder to read for other users because of the issue of not being able to step through.
I would limit this to cases where the proof is principled (like applying a constructor and be done with it), and resort to goal selectors for factorisation.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I understand why it can't be step through now. But do people often write proof manual first and then summarize it to a more compact one? Or, do they just write down proof script and fix error until it passes? Or, do they only write such undebugable script when it's obviously right?

Comment: If you find my answer satisfactory you can mark it as accepted. This is a question of style I think now. I think people do go step by step before getting the hang of it and going for a more concise version. Again, more concise doesn't necessarily mean better. If if makes it harder to maintain or less accessible, I don't think you should do it. And yeah unfortunately, some people write undebuggable stuff even when they shouldn't (to my mind).